# An example of using CSVW in RDFa?

Tags: csv, metadata, rdf, rdfa

Could someone provide me with an example of how to implement **[CSVW](https://www.w3.org/ns/csvw#class-definitions)** standard to describe the columns and rows of a CSV dataset in **RDFa** format?

The only documentation I seem to find about this is here, which is rather limited: https://www.w3.org/blog/2016/02/added-the-csvw-prefix-to-the-rdfa-initial-context/